# Windows Azure and MongoDb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure

**Description:**
Im trying to get MongoDb up and running using windows azure. As they described [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/windows-azure/), they used a worker role instances to run mongod servers, and blob storage to store mongodb data.
In their code from [github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-azure/), they use `CloudDrive` class to mount a virtual drive of the blob container. (`GetMountedPathFromBlob` function in the `Utilities` class in the `MongoDbRole` project)
they do it like that so they can still invoke `mongod` process with a `--dbpath` argument.

**My problem:**
There is no `CloudDrive` class in the new 2.x sdk anymore(deprecated). How can I do the same (mount a virtual drive) so I can invoke `mongod` process correctly inside my worker role.

**Suggestions:**
I found a class [CloudBlobDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory_members.aspx)  maybe it can resolve the probleme, or [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.aspx). Im still reading lots of docs trying to 
takle this problem.

the idea is to create a virtual drive in the worker role instance, pointing to the blob container ?

Any suggestions ??

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately the `mongo-azure` project has not kept up with the Azure APIs. It looks like the issue you are hitting is already tracked as [AZURE-72](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/AZURE-72), which you could watch and/or upvote. If possible, I think a better option at the moment would be to use one of the MongoDB-as-a-Service [cloud hosting partners](http://www.mongodb.com/partners/cloud).

Comment: @Stennie thanks, at least im not the only one :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: You can use Azure VM and install your MongoDB. You can connect to this VM from web/worker role so they are located in the same cloud service with your VM.

Solution 2: Check out MongoLab in Azure Store. It's a Mongo-as-a-service which you don't need to take care of the installation, configuration, etc. http://blog.shaunxu.me/archive/2013/03/27/consume-third-party-services-at-windows-azure-store.aspx

Comment: solution1: means that i need to maintain and upgrade the vm (not good).
solution2: GREAT !! thanks for the tip mongolab seems to be a good solution.
before i mark this answer, i need to know: are you saying that there is no way to do it like the old sdk did. (ie mounting the blob as a virtual drive)